# learning approach for an expert system

Tags: machine-learning, classification

- Step 1: I developed an expert system that classifies data into two classes, each rule in this expert system has a certainty factor (expert opinions).
- Step 2: The input of the system is a group of sentences and the output is classified sentences into two classes like c1, c2.
- Step 3: The user has to mark the sentences placed in the wrong.
- Step 4: the system shall edit rules certainty factors depending on the user's feedback, to make the system more accurate.

I want a machine learning algorithm that uses my rules to classify the data.

not: l have a labeled dataset

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please provide us with a bit more step-by-step information about what you mean? So step 1, you have a model that makes a binary prediction, with an associated probability/certainty. Step 2, you want to somehow combine a user input along with the model's output to generate a more accurate prediction? Or do you mean you want this same model to take into account a user's opinion, before giving prediction? I hope you understand the kind of information that is lacking, please clarify your question and I can have a crack at it.

Comment: depending on what "learn from users' feedback" looks like, this is either an example of [tag:online-algorithms] or [tag:reinforcement-learning], both of which are large topics. Please [edit] to be more specific about what particular problem you're facing and what you would like to know.

Comment: @VladimirBelik I edit it, I hope it is clear to you now

Comment: Alright, I understand your procedure, but don't fully understand your question. Are you asking what algorithm you should use to edit your list of rules based on user's feedback?

Comment: @VladimirBelik Yes, I want a method based on feedback from users that calibrates the certainty factor for the rules.

Comment: I think that is a near-impossible and probably unnecessary task. What you should do is have a machine learning algorithm BE the expert. Give it information and the correct answers, and it will figure out the best rules by constantly correcting/adjusting itself against the list of correct (user determined, perhaps) answers you give it.

Comment: okay, Which algorithm do you know to recommend to classify texts?

Comment: To be clear, I don't think you should toss out those rules you made. You can transform them into features to feed into the ML model, and the model will decide how much to weight each feature. You're asking about the algorithm - is your data in tabular form? (Like, a regular dataset with rows of examples, columns of features + column with correct answer)?

Comment: I have a labeled dataset written as a CSV file, like 
(sentence, class)

Comment: Perfect. If you can open the question back up, I will provide you with a detailed answer.

Comment: Hi @VladimirBelik, My question is reopening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers, OP and I had a small back and forth in the comments under his question that clarified what he was working on.

**Direct answer to the posed question:**

I think doing exactly what you asked (having an ML tool adjust your existing rules) is effectively impossible (extremely complex task).

**My recommendation:**

Instead of having ML adjust your existing "expert" rules, you should just have an ML algorithm *become* your "expert". You mentioned you have a labelled dataset, so you should just treat this as a supervised learning problem, where it is up to the ML algorithm to become the expert and "decide" what the best rules are for classifying your text. Again, since your dataset is already labelled (since you already know the correct classification for each sentence), your ML algorithm will receive constant feedback and try to adjust to get the best result.

Now the harder question is: "What data do I give the ML model so that it can make these predictions?"

Well, this is where your existing expert rules come in. Don't throw them away! You can transform them into features for the learner, and the learner will decide how to weight/utilize that information.

There's two ways you can do this. Let's say, as an easy example, that one of your expert rules is that "If sentence is longer than 7 words, it's generally class 1 and if it's shorter, it's generally class 2". From this rule, you can extract two features:
One feature is to feed "number of words in sentence" to the algorithm, and it will try to find the best cut off point (maybe it's 9 and not 7). You feed it the same data your rules use, and let it make the determination.
The second thing you can do is along with that raw data "number of words in sentence", you can feed in some kind of binary 1/0 determination based on your existing rules, so that the algorithm can potentially weight that in as well.

So for the same example, you have two features. Based on that rule you already have, you can feed in the # words in sentence, plus your own expert determination of what the class "should" be based on that information.

I hope this makes sense.

For the ML model, I would heavily recommend RandomForest. It easily handles different kinds of inputs (categorical, numerical etc.), it has few hyperparameters you need to tune, is quick to train, generally has great performance, and it gives an easily interpretable probability output associated with each class prediction. It's just overall a very "plug and play", beginner-friendly algorithm compared to others, and it generally delivers comparable results to other algorithms.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! I will read about RandomForest. really it Looks great idea.

Comment: @Eng.sh Fantastic! :) Did I fully answer your question?

Comment: Yes!  you did, I read some about RandomForest I seems simple Algorithm, I hope to get high accuracy with it. If not do you recommend another ML model, please?

Comment: @Eng.sh Great! In such case, please consider accepting the answer :) If you do not get good results with RandomForest, another model *probably* won't save you. You will need to do more feature engineering (it's generally much more important than the model you use).